# Bonsai Elasticsearch Heroku unknown error 52

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm getting unknown error:52 when trying to connect to my Bonsai Elasticsearch on heroku.

I use FOSElastica with Symfony. It has worked before, but suddenly it has stopped.

These are my settings:

`fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            host: %elasticsearch.host%
            port: %elasticsearch.port%
            headers:
                Authorization: "Basic %elasticsearch.token%"`

Where the elasticsearch.token is generated using this:

```
php -r "Print base64_encode('your_auth_username' . ':' . 'your_auth_password');"
```

My host is of the format:
username:password@myhost.net

And my port is: 443 (80 doesn't work as wel).

No further logging is given ...

Answer (score 0):

Try remove headers, it helped me.